# Letter segmentation: openCV findContours does not work

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation

I have a binary image contains a word, I want to slice the image into pieces, each contains a single character.

[image][image]

I tried to use opencv's findcontours to get the bounding box of each character. However, the findContours does not work as expect.

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

How should I solve this issue? 
Is another a better approach for this?

Comment: FindContours works as expected. _Your_ expectations are wrong. You can't solve this simply getting connected components.

Comment: What is the correct approach?